# ruby 'mikel/mail' reply-to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mail-gem

I'm parsing an email using the below style

```
message = Mail.new(body)   #where body is the RAW source from the email server
message.subject #=> the subject of the message as a string
message.from #=> shows who the email is from
```

How would I get a value of the 'reply-to' field if it exists? Can the gem do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the `reply_to` method:

```
message.reply_to
# => ["user@example.com"]
```

If there was no reply-to set, it'll be nil:

```
message.reply_to
# => nil
```

I'd recommend looking through the [RDoc documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/mikel/mail/frames), specifically for the [Message object](http://rdoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message). This will show you all of the methods available on your `message` instance.

Comment: That RDoc is better than mine I used the `gem server` one which was bit empty